# Prolog - finding all path options

Tags: prolog, parameter-passing, path-finding

One piece of the program I am writing in Prolog has to do with finding all possible path options from the starting location to the ending location.

Here is what I have so far:

```
findAllRoutes(Start, End, Path) :-
     findAllRoutes(Start, _, End, Path),
     print('Successful route: '), print(Route).

findAllRoutes(End, _, End, [End]). %route was successfully finished

 findAllRoutes(Start, Temp, End, [Start|Rest_of_List]) :-
     path(Start, Temp),
     findAllRoutes(Temp, _, End, Rest).
```

Here is the data to be read in:

```
%path(Start, End).
path(1, 4). %find all the possible paths from location 1 to location 4.

%paths_in_place[[Start, End, Distance]].
paths_in_place[[1, 2, 250], [2, 4, 250], [1, 3, 400], [3, 4, 300]].
```

My question is, is this an accurate way to cycle through `paths_in_place` while also saving the order of the points reached on the way from the starting location to the ending location?

Also, what happens to `Distance`when `findAllRoutes`is called without any mention of the `Distance` field? Is it legal in Prolog to pass the parameters of `Start, End, Route`even though in `paths_in_place` the fields are `Start, End, Distance`?

Any help is much appreciated. Let me know if I need to clarify anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prolog data are symbolic. You could be passing distance in meters, and treat it as distance in feet. That's how one of Mars missions got crashed, although they used another language. So it's ultimately up to you.

As to your code,

```
findAllRoutes(Start, End, Path) :-
     findAllRoutes(Start, _, End, Path),
     print('Successful route: '), print(Route).
```

`Route`? What `Route`? It's an uninstantiated "singleton" variable. SWI Prolog warns us to that effect. Perhaps you meant `Path`.

```
findAllRoutes(End, _, End, [End]).  % route was successfully finished

findAllRoutes(Start, Temp, End, [Start|Rest_of_List]) :-
     path(Start, Temp),
     findAllRoutes(Temp, _, End, Rest).
```

again, `Rest_of_List` and `Rest` probably should have the same name (be the same logical variable).

Otherwise it looks OK, except for its name: it finds one path, not "AllRoutes", on each invocation/backtracking. The name "AllRoutes" suggests it finds all of them and returns them all in its result argument; it's not.

Then comes your data and it's out of sync with your code:

```
%path(Start, End).
path(1, 4). %find all the possible paths from location 1 to location 4.

%paths_in_place[[Start, End, Distance]].
paths_in_place([[1, 2, 250], [2, 4, 250], [1, 3, 400], [3, 4, 300]]).
  % ! must be in parentheses !
```

Your `path(Start, Temp)` call in your code suggests `Temp` is an immediate successor to `Start`. Not so according to these data. Plus, `path/2` definition is missing. But you can just have a bunch of facts instead of the list to define the data.